# How to keep stubbed response in Cypress up-to-date with reality?

Tags: json, mocking, cypress, stubbing

Does somebody have any idea how stubbed responses (Cypress fixture json files) can be best kept up-to-date with reality so that the stubbed response always matches an actual possible server response, from both structural point of view and valid values point of view. I think it can soon lead to situation that a given test will give false positives and the mismatch(es) in stubbed vs. real data might be left unnoticed for long time.

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/activities/*', { fixture: 'activities.json' })
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what use case do you have where you cannot just used the real response? Why stub at all here when the real response value is what you seem to be after? Honestly curious, not trying to be judgmental.

Comment: One reason somebody mentioned in a discussion could be speed.
But I can imagine a situation when you need to test a complex UI where the GET request returns a json of e.g. 100 lines. And to get to that specific state you need to do a heavy preparation steps before to setup supporting data (e.g. calling 30 POST requests or go through long setup in UI), so that you can finally get the 100-lines json for that tested page. But it seems to me it would be very difficult to ensure the json (for that tested page = for the last step of the flow) is always valid and up-to-date with reality.

Comment: Anyway, I think it’s better to first ensure that imlemented functionality is fully-integrated into the system one small piece at a time and that there are appropriate lower-level tests (unit, int) implemented, to mitigate fragility of such long-flow scenarios.